# Name does not exist in this context UNITY

Tags: unity-game-engine, github

Error: Assets\PlayMaker\GrapplingHook.cs(79,96): error CS0103: The name 'GRAPPLING_NODE_TAG' does not exist in the current context

Line:if (disconent_on_los_break && Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit) && hit.collider.tag != GRAPPLING_NODE_TAG)

I found this script in a github and I am not very sure why there is an error

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a tag in the scene with the name "GRAPPLING_NODE_TAG". To do this, go to any gameobject, go to the inspector after selecting the gameobject, and click on the tag button under the "tag" text. Then click "add tag", and click on the plus. name it "GRAPPLING_NODE_TAG", and hit play.